# Using Regex with react router

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to have a route like mysite.com/hotel-newyork-123 in react using react router. 
The regular expression is **/.+-.+-\d/g**. Now i want the same to be implemented in react app. I searched tutorials but i didnt find a simple implementation of regex.Please post a working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It supports regex inside parenthesis.
This should work for you:

```
<Route path='/(.+-.+-\d+)' component={MyComponent} />
```

Comment: I tried that. It didnt work.Can you plz post a working example.

Comment: Your regex is not good, there's a missing + at the end if you want to match hotel-newyork-123